# How to Override the Head of a Symbol

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, core-language

I was wondering if it is possible to override the head of symbols/operators. As a motivating example if I run:

[image: example]

Then Ket will be returned. But lets say I want Bob to be returned instead of Ket. Is such a thing possible? To go a little bit further, I'd like:

[image: bob]
to return BobKet and

[image: alice]

to return AliceKet so that I could make a function that recognizes these heads like:
[image: function]

Thanks!

Here are the corresponding lines of code

`Head[Ket[\[Placeholder]]]`

`Head[Ket[Subscript[x, B]]]`

`Head[Ket[Subscript[x, A]]]`

`combineBobAndAlice[b_BobKet, a_AliceKet] := Ket[{
   {Subscript[b[[1, 1]], B], Subscript[a[[1, 1]], A]}
  }]`

Comment: Please post your code as text that we can copy and paste to duplicate your results.

Comment: `Apply` is usually used to change the head of an expression.

Comment: that is true. I do not think you can change head of an Atom. Try `Clear[bob]; r=1; r[[0]]=bob` you'll get an error. But `r = Sin[x]; r[[0]]=bob` works. Now `Head[r]` returns `bob`. I think playing games with Heads to do what is asked here is the wrong way to go about writing a program.

Comment: Nasser, thanks for that idea, it has pointed me in the right direction I think.

Answer (score 7):

I don't believe it is possible to implement your literal request.  While you can make an [`UpSet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UpSet.html) definition for `Head`:

```
Unprotect[Ket];
Head[Ket[_]] ^:= Bob
Head[Ket[Subscript[x, B]]] ^:= BobKet
Head[Ket[Subscript[x, A]]] ^:= AliceKet

Head[Ket[Subscript[x, B]]]
```

> ```
> BobKet
> ```

Since `Head` is not actually used by the pattern matcher this does not produce your desired behavior:

```
f[_BobKet] := "hit!"
f[Ket[Subscript[x, B]]]
```

> ```
> f[Ket[Subscript[x, B]]]
> ```

(I don't actually have `Ket` in version 7, but I see no reason for this not to work unless `Ket` is atomic.)

However, I can see no *need* for this behavior.  Instead you should simply use a pattern that matches what you want it to match.  You can assign patterns to global Symbols to use them easily, if that is your concern:

```
bob = HoldPattern @ Ket[Subscript[x, B]];
alice = HoldPattern @ Ket[Subscript[x, A]];

f[x : bob, y : alice] := {"it worked!", x, y}

f[Ket[Subscript[x, B]], Ket[Subscript[x, A]]]
```

> ```
> {"it worked!", Ket[Subscript[x, B]], Ket[Subscript[x, A]]}
> ```

You can even use named patterns within a pattern, e.g.:

```
bob = HoldPattern @ Ket[Subscript[u_, B]];
alice = HoldPattern @ Ket[Subscript[v_, A]];

f[x : bob, y : alice] := {u, v}

f[Ket[Subscript[foo, B]], Ket[Subscript[bar, A]]]
```

> ```
> {foo, bar}
> ```

I hope this helps you implement what you need.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37583/discussion-on-answer-by-mr-wizard-how-to-override-the-head-of-a-symbol).