# Generic templating system

Tags: argument-patterns

I'm trying to implement a templating system in Mathematica, a bit like the `List<List<T>>` you would find in C#.

Here's how it looks so far:

```
ClearAll[ListOf];
ListOf /: ListOf[ListOf[f_Symbol]] := Function[l, ListQ[l] && ListOf[f][First@l]];
ListOf[f_Symbol] := 
  Function[l, 
    ListQ[l] && (l == {} || Head[First[l]] === f || f[First[l]])] /; (f =!= ListOf);
```

My goal is to make it easier to spot what the arguments of a function look like:

```
f[l_?(ListOf[String])] := l;
f[l_?(ListOf[ListOf[String]])] := l;
```

However, multi-level definition won't work because `ListOf[f]` is replaced:

```
ListOf[Integer][{1, 2, 3}] (* True *)
ListOf[ListOf[Integer]][{{1, 2, 3}}] (* Inner ListOf[Integer] is evaluated *)
```

I've fiddled with `HoldPattern` and `UpValues` but I couldn't get it working.

Also please note the `f[First[l]]` is to also accept arguments such as `ListOf[NumericQ]`.

Comment: I believe these are related: [(1276)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1276/121),
[(4636)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4636/121),
[(41253)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41253/121),
[(52057)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/52057/121).  Also see: [(23345)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23345/121), [(85821)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85821/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### General

I will show two (similar) ways of doing something like what you requested. Both are based on reusing the `` TypeSystem` ``  package, which is built in V10+. This package has several predefined types - inert symbols to denote them, actually. In particular, it has `Atom`, `Vector`, `Tuple`, `Assoc` and `Struct`, with `Atom` and `Vector` immediately relevant for us.

#### Using `` TypeSystem` ``

We need to load the package first:

```
<<TypeSystem`
```

Now, we can do a few things. For example, this would be our test data:

```
dt = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}}
dtragged = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e"}}
```

We can use the function `DeduceType`, to deduce the types of these:

```
t = DeduceType[dt]
tr = DeduceType[dtragged]

(*
  Vector[Vector[Atom[String], 3], 2]

  Vector[Vector[Atom[String], AnyLength], 2]
*)
```

We can also generate the type-validation function, using `DataValidationFunction`, like so:

```
vf = DataValidationFunction[t]

(* Length[#1] == 2 && MatrixQ[#1, StringQ[#1] ||  GeneralUtilities`MissingQ[#1] &] && Length[#1[[1]]] == 3 & *)
```

or

```
vfr = DataValidationFunction[tr]

(* ListQ[#1] && Length[#1] == 2 && VectorQ[#1, VectorQ[#1, StringQ[#1] || GeneralUtilities`MissingQ[#1] &] &] & *)
```

There are many other things one can do, but these are sufficient for our purposes.

#### Custom assignment operator using TypeSystem

We can now define a custom assignment operator, that would preprocess your definitions:

```
ClearAll[defTS];
SetAttributes[defTS, HoldAll];
defTS[(h : (Set | SetDelayed))[lhs_, rhs_]] :=
   h @@ Append[
      Hold[lhs] /. t : _Vector | _Atom :>
        With[{vf = DataValidationFunction[t]}, (_?vf) /; True], 
      Unevaluated[rhs]
   ]
```

It uses the Trott - Strzebonski technique to inject into held code. Here is an example:

```
defTS[ff[a : Vector[Vector[Atom[String], AnyLength], 2]] := Length[a]]
```

The resulting definition is then:

```
?ff
```

> ```
>    Global`ff
>
>    ff[a:_?(ListQ[#1]&&Length[#1]==2&&VectorQ[#1,VectorQ[#1,StringQ[#1]||GeneralUtilities`MissingQ[#1]&]&]&)]:=Length[a]
> ```

#### Compiling to patterns

We could also, instead of using the `DataValidationFunction`, reuse just the syntactic part of what `` TypeSystem` ``  provides, and "compile" that to patterns, which are familiar and idiomatic way to test arguments. Here is a simple example:

```
ClearAll[compile];
compile[Atom[atomType_]] := _atomType;
compile[Vector[Atom[atomType_], AnyLength]] := {___atomType};
compile[Vector[type_, AnyLength]] := {compile[type] ...};
compile[Vector[type_, length_Integer]] := {Repeated[compile[type], length]};
```

For example:

```
compile[t]
compile[tr]

(*
   {Repeated[{Repeated[_String, 3]}, 2]}

   {Repeated[{___String}, 2]}
*)
```

Now, we can do something similar to what we did before: define a custom assignment operator:

```
ClearAll[def];
SetAttributes[def, HoldAll];
def[(h : (Set | SetDelayed))[lhs_, rhs_]] := 
  h @@ Append[
     Hold[lhs] /. t : _Vector | _Atom :> RuleCondition[compile[t]], 
     Unevaluated[rhs]
  ]
```

where I use a shorter form of Trott - Strzebonski technique, which uses `RuleCondition`. Now, if we use this one,

```
def[f[a : Vector[Vector[Atom[String], AnyLength], 2]] := Length[a]]
```

we get the following definition generated:

```
?f
```

> ```
>     Global`f
>
>     f[a:{Repeated[{___String},2]}]:=Length[a]
> ```

One can extend `compile` to handle more cases. As shown, it is very simplistic, just to illustrate the idea.

At this point, however, we may ask, whether it was worth the trouble to start with the `` TypeSystem` `` , if all we want is to define argument tests for a function, using just usual patterns. The conciseness of patterns is probably one reason why people generally don't bother with formal generics / template system just for the purposes of defining functions - in any particular case it is usually much simpler to just write the relevant patterns.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer! I had no idea this library existed. Does any documentation exists for `TypeSystem`? It doesn't seem to be installed on my system and Google doesn't return much.

Comment: No, there isn't currently any documentation. This is a new development, it only exists in version 10. It is currently mostly used by `Dataset`, but can have uses on its own too.